# What's the meaning of ($x^2$) when we compute a Taylor's polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

I'm confused. I've seen people write "+($x^2$)" at the end of a Taylor Expansion countless times and I understand it has to do with the uncalculated terms, but where does the $x^2$ come from? How does it work?

Comment: see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) article

Comment: It means that the remaining terms are no bigger than some constant multiple of $x^2$ $-$ see [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). There is an implied "as $x\to 0$" (but in other contexts there may be an implied "as $x\to\infty$"). Note that it is usually written with a normal $O$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\cal O}(x^2)$ simply means terms that are of order $x^2$ or higher.  This is called "big-oh" notation, which has a formal definition.  Anyway, informally:

Thus $f(x) = a + b x + c x^2 + d x^3 + e x^4$ can be written $f(x) = a + b x + {\cal O}(x^2)$.

You could also write $f(x) = a + b x + c x^2 + {\cal O}(x^3)$

... and so on.